# Migrar base de dados

Tags: xampp

Colegas.

Tivemos um problema em um computador do qual tivemos que formatá-lo, porém mantivemos os arquivos e tivemos que reinstalar os programas, entre eles o Xampp. A pasta que ficou foi o c:/xampp, então renomeamos para c:/xampp_old e fizemos a reinstalação.

O problema está na migração do banco de dados. Abrimos a pasta c:/xampp_old/mysql/data/ e copiamos as pastas dos bancos de dados que foram criados antes da formatação e jogamos para a pasta que o Xampp criou c:/xampp/mysql/data/ , mas quando fizemos isso, o mysql dá erro, não inicia.

Como fazemos para migrar as base de dados do xampp antigo para o novo?

Answer (score 2):

Ola, necessitei realizar um procedimento semelhante e segue a solução que apliquei:

1 - Abri o Painel de Controle do meu  c:/xampp_old e startei apenas o serviço mysql;

2 - Então abri o Painel de Controle do Meu c:/xampp e startei o Apache;

3 - Acessei o PhpMyAdmin do c:/xampp e conectei na Base do MySql startada no c:/xampp_old e realizei a Exportação completa dos Bancos de Dados para arquivo .sql;

4 - Realizei a exportação das contas de Usuários juntamente com as permissões de acesso as estes bancos e salvei também em arquivo .sql;

5 - Finalizei a conexão do PhpMyAdmin e parei o MySQL do painel de controle do c:/xampp_old;

6 - Startei o MySQL do Painel de Controle do c:/xampp;

7 - Acessei o PhpMyAdmin e conectei, desta vez estará conectando no novo MySQL;

8 - Executei a importação dos SQL primeiro importando o Banco e Depois importando as Permissões;

9 - Como exportei o Usuário Root no meu caso meu PhpMyAdmin perdeu a conexão após a execução, sendo necessário logar novamente, mas já com o Usuário e Senha que tinha configurado no MySQL anterior.

OBS: Sei que a pergunta foi realizada a tempo, mas espero que seja util para quem precisar realizer este procedimento.
No Meu caso realizei o mesmo para atualizar toda a minha estrutura de Xampp para uma versão mais recente.

Caso alguem tenha dificuldade para executar estes processos no detalhe, pode retornar com questionamento.